# Finishing script/function execution when error occurs

Tags: matlab, error-handling, fopen

I'm using function that reads and process structured files:

```
fname=strcat(folder,'\',fname);
FID=fopen(fname);
% reading lines and digging and procsesing data using fgetl() and regexp()
fclose(FID);
```

When there's any error in *reading and digging* part an error message is thrown but the file is opened and FID pointer is lost. Mostly it's caused by missing or wrong line.

How can I avoid losing the FID pointer (for manual closing) when error occurs and/or execute `fclose(FID)` when error occurs?
Or is there a way how to open a file wihout locking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use a [`try`-`catch`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block. In fact, you don't even need the `catch` here:

```
fname = strcat(folder,'\',fname); %\\'
FID = fopen(fname);
try
    %// reading lines and digging and procsesing data using fgetl() and regexp()
    %// errors in this part are not shown
end
fclose(FID); %// this gets executed even if there were errors in reading and digging
```

Or, if you want to show the errors:

```
fname = strcat(folder,'\',fname); %\\'
FID = fopen(fname);
try
    %// reading lines and digging and procsesing data using fgetl() and regexp()
catch
    e = lasterror;
    fprintf(2,'%s\n',e.message); %// show message in red
end
fclose(FID); %// this gets executed even if there were errors in reading and digging
```

Or show the error but closing the file first:

```
fname = strcat(folder,'\',fname); %\\'
FID = fopen(fname);
try
    %// reading lines and digging and procsesing data using fgetl() and regexp()
catch ME
    fclose(FID); %// close file
    error(ME.message) %// issue error
end
fclose(FID);
```

Comment: If there are commands related to variables created while digging, using `try`...`catch fclose(FID); return; end` would force the execution to stop and would avoid another errors, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I unserstand your question in te eabove comment. The _first_ error in the `try` block causes execution to go to the `catch` part. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. And it should close the file properly and terminate further execution, which WILL lead to another error.

Comment: Approach I've tried was to return FID to the workspace. In case of an error I can call `fclose(returnedFID)` but it is awful hack. Your code is a solution. Thanks.